# How to show available props options in React Element in VS Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

i am just wondering how to show some available props for one component in React while using VS Code

for example when i have this component

```
export function CustomWarning = (props)=>{

  return <Modal show={props.show} onClose={props.onClose} type={props.type}/>

}

CustomWarning.propTypes ={
  show : PropTypes.bool,
  onClose : PropTypes.func,
  type : PropTypes.oneOf(["modalA","modalB"])
}
```

how do i show the options are `modalA` and `modalB` when i import my component somewhere and it shows available props automatically?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

EDIT:
There are 2 ways: rewrite the component to ts, or utilize a `d.ts` file. Old answer below will answer the former.

#### Using `d.ts`

You can create a `d.ts` file with the exact same name with your `js` component, like :

```
type modalOptions = 'modalA' | 'modalB'

interface ModalProps {
  show : boolean,
  // in this case i say this function will not return anything
  onClose: ()=>void,
  type?: modalOptions
}

declare const Modal (props: ModalProps){}

export default Modal;
```

this way you will not need to modify your `js` file but akin to giving instructions to anyone how to use your component.
Remember this file wont change how your js file work, it just some sort of contract for other to follow.

---

Old Answer

#### Rewrite to `ts`

Actually, you can if you opt in for Typescript.

you can define your `Modal` such as

```js
// Modal.tsx
type modalOptions = 'modalA' | 'modalB'

interface ModalProps {
  show : boolean,
  // in this case i say this function will not return anything
  onClose: ()=>void,
  type?: modalOptions
}


const Modal: FunctionComponent<ModalProps> = (
  {show, onClose, type}
)=>{
  return // your implementations here
}
```

so later when you type, you will see this

[image: typing type props to Modal Component]

nice and clean.